# IntellliJ doens't change java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following error in my intelliJ project

```
   Error:(136, 14) java: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I go to preferences and change the compiler from 1.5 to 8. 
This error still appearing, I am trying also restart and rebuild, but it didn't help. 
Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you have tried.  There are a couple of places in preferences where you may have to change the compiler.

Comment: In Project Structure, click Modules->"Your modules"->Dependencies to see what SDK you are using.

Comment: You have code related to JDK1.8, but the idea does not recognize the newly installed JDK1.8 input `java -version` to check what version is now